# How do you insert markers into a Silverlight LIVE video stream?

Tags: silverlight, streaming, live, closed-captions, timelinemarkers

A client has a live video stream and a Silverlight player, we would like to add closed captions to the player.  However, due to lag we need a way of synchronising the video and the captions.

TimelineMarkers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.timelinemarker(VS.95).aspx) seems like the way to archive this, however, I can't find an example of how to insert them into a live stream.

Im looking for something like this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/metadata_video_streaming_print.html but for Silverlight.

Comment: I just realized how old this question was :)

Comment: no, the whole project was abandon ...

Answer (score -2):

You can dynamically add Markers to the media element in the following manner:

```
TimelineMarker marker = new TimelineMarker();
marker.Text = "Some caption text...";
marker.Time = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 00);
mediaElement.Markers.Add(marker);
```